# Bluetooth Autoreconnect HM10 Bluetooth Serial

Tags: ios, swift, bluetooth, hm-10

I am using [HM10-BluetoothSerial-iOS](https://github.com/hoiberg/HM10-BluetoothSerial-iOS) as base for my own application where I remotly control an AtMega.

I wish to automatically reconnect to the HM10 Bluetooth device. As far as I know you cannot store `CBPeripherals` for a later connection. So how can I reconnect at a later time?

Comment: You can store the peripheral's identifier and the use CBCentral method `retrievePeripheralWithIdentifier` to get the CBPeripheral and then connect to that. RetrievePeripheral... May return nil, in which case you need to search again.

Comment: Hello, do you mean the UUID ?
Is this the FFE0 / FFE1 which is fixed in the HM10 ?

Comment: I saw that it already searchs for new peripherals with:
centralManager.scanForPeripheralsWithServices([uuid], options: nil)
let peripherals = centralManager.retrieveConnectedPeripheralsWithServices([uuid])

Is it true, that I cannot connect to a specific device, that means, if I have two HM10, with the same name and the same UUID, I can't decide if I was connected to the one or the other, the last time?

Comment: Two peripheral's won't have the same UUID. The will both offer the same service UUID, but the peripheral `identifier` will be unique. You can store `peripheral.identifier.UUIDString` And use that to retrieve the peripheral later

Comment: Thank you, now it's possible to reconnect to the last device.
But for now I use 2 timers, first timer fires after 0.5 Seconds after the ViewDidLoad is executed and try to connect to the device, the second timer 1 second after that, reloads everything and checks whether is is connected or not. Is there a possibility to get an interrupt as soon as the bluetooth is available, so that I can use the connect method?

Comment: Once you have retrieved the CBPeripheral you can just issue the `connect`, even if the peripheral isn't currently in range. . You will get a delegate callback once the connection completes.